# Error 404 in working with post actions on asp.net mvc 5 in IIS 8.5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis

I have a problem with actions that have POST attribute.
when I used of IIS Express Server everything is OK , but when I use of Local IIS just GET actions worked fine, and when call post actions in my web application give me following error:

> HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
>   The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.

for example this action in CallController:

```
[HttpPost]
    public PartialViewResult Connecting(FarakhanModels fara)
    {
        try
        {
            fara.IP = fara.IP.Trim();
            IPAddress IP = IPAddress.Parse(fara.IP);

            socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork,
            SocketType.Stream,
            ProtocolType.Tcp);

            socket.Connect(IP, fara.Port);

            fara.IsConnected = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            fara.ErrorMessage = ex.Message;
            fara.IsConnected = false;
        }

        return (PartialView(viewName: "_Partial_Connect", model: fara));
    }
```

with this view:

```
<h4>Call group</h4>
<hr />
<div id="connect">
    <div id="loading">
        <img src="~/Images/ajax-loader.gif" title="loading" />
        Loading... Please Wati !
</div>

<br />

<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
    <span class="col-md-3">Connect to server:</span>
    <input type="search" id="ip" />
</div>

<br />
<br />

<div class="col-md-9 col-sm-10">
    <span class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">Port:</span>
    <input type="search" id="port" />
</div>

<br />
<br />
<br />

<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-3">
    <button type="button" class="btn-primary" id="btnConnect">Connect</button>
    @*<input type="button" id="btnConnect" name="btnConnect" value="Connect" style="width:120px" />*@
</div>
<div class="col-md-12" id="message">

</div>


<br />
<br />
```

```
@section Scripts {
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("div#loading").hide();
        $("div#call").hide();

        $("button#btnConnect").click(function () {
            $("div#message").html("");

            $("div#loading").show();
            $("button#btnConnect").hide();

            var varIp = $("input#ip").val();
            var varPort = $("input#port").val();

            var varData =
                {
                    ip: varIp,
                    port: varPort,
                };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "html",
                data: varData,
                url: "/Call/Connecting",
                error: function (response) {
                    $("div#message").html(response.error.toString());
                },

                success: function (response) {
                    $("input#ip").val("");
                    $("input#port").val("");

                    $("div#call").show();
                    $("div#connect").hide();
                    $("div#partialView").html(response);
                },

                complete: function (response) {
                    $("div#loading").hide();
                    $("button#btnConnect").show();
                }

            })
        })
    })
</script>

    }
```

when I click on Connect button, Ajax not found the Url:/Call/Connecting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suspicion would be the url used in the ajax call:

```
url: "/Call/Connecting"
```

It is going from the root path.  You'd get 404 if you deployed the app in an environment where "/Call" is not the root.  For instance, if you deployed your app at http://example.com/my_cool_app.  Then the url should be "/my_cool_app/Call/Connecting" instead.  I'd recommend using Url.Action helper to build your action endpoint dynamically instead of hard coding it.

Comment: thanks, very helpful. I used of '@Url.Action("Connecting","Call")' and it's worked!